# React-redux app is no longer auto updating

Tags: react-redux, webpack-2, sass-loader

I had a react-redux app working perfectly fine with the UI being auto updated after every file change, then I decided to plugin sass into my app and the auto-reloading stopped working. So in order to get sass in my app, I had to install sass-loader, node-sass, css-loader, etc. But one of the loaders needed webpack 2, so I switched from 1.15 to 2.0, now when I run "npm run dev" I see webpack recompile after every file change, but my UI isn't being auto reloaded in my browser. Can anyone help me troubleshoot this?

Here is my webpack config file:

```
var debug = process.env.NODE_ENV !== "production";
var webpack = require('webpack');
var path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  context: path.join(__dirname, "src"),
  devtool: debug ? "inline-sourcemap" : null,
  entry: "./js/app.js",
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        exclude: /(node_modules)/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        query: {
          presets: ['react', 'es2015', 'stage-0'],
          plugins: ['react-html-attrs', 'transform-class-properties', 'transform-decorators-legacy', "transform-object-rest-spread"],
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        loader: 'style-loader!css-loader!sass-loader'
      }
    ]
  },
  output: {
    path: __dirname + "/src/",
    filename: "app.min.js"
  },
  plugins: debug ? [] : [
    new webpack.optimize.DedupePlugin(),
    new webpack.optimize.OccurenceOrderPlugin(),
    new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({ mangle: false, sourcemap: false }),
  ],
};
```

An here is my package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "campaign-viewer",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "description": "Code challenge from MediaMath",
  "main": "webpack.config.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.12.0",
    "babel-core": "^6.18.2",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.0",
    "babel-plugin-add-module-exports": "^0.1.2",
    "babel-plugin-react-html-attrs": "^2.0.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-class-properties": "^6.3.13",
    "babel-plugin-transform-decorators-legacy": "^1.3.4",
    "babel-plugin-transform-object-rest-spread": "^6.23.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.3.13",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.3.13",
    "babel-preset-stage-0": "^6.3.13",
    "css-loader": "^0.28.4",
    "moment": "^2.18.1",
    "node-sass": "^4.5.3",
    "react": "^0.14.6",
    "react-datetime": "^2.8.10",
    "react-dom": "^0.14.6",
    "react-redux": "^4.4.5",
    "redux": "^3.6.0",
    "redux-logger": "^2.6.1",
    "redux-promise-middleware": "^3.2.0",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.1.0",
    "sass-loader": "^6.0.6",
    "style-loader": "^0.18.2",
    "webpack": "^2.0.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^1.14.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {},
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "./node_modules/.bin/webpack-dev-server --content-base src --inline --hot",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "Chris Stephenson",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the problem was with using webpack-dev-server. When I used version 2.0.0 instead of 1.14.1 it started auto reloading again.